# Laptop black screen on start up?

Tags: boot, laptop, dell-inspiron, black-screen-of-death

I'm attempting to repair my girlfriends Laptop (Dell 501R).

It was working fine but she had a problem with overheating cutting the power, I opened it up and gave i a dusting and applied new thermal paste. However when I've attempted to turn it back on the whole laptop doesn't boot up.

It has a black screen with a few of the bottom LED's lit up. No sound coming from the fans or from the DVD drive booting up.  I've tried a few fixes to no avail.

- Opening up and checking all cables are connected
- Taking battery and attempting to boot
- Taking battery out, holding for 30 seconds to release static and attempting to boot
- Taking the RAM cards out and cleaning contacts with an eraser.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

- Re-check the cables, you're never sure enough.
- Check if you can wiggle the BIOS chip. I've had a similar issue where it appeared that my BIOS chip was a little loose, so I had it soldered again which resulted in a booting laptop. This is probably my best guess on why the laptop isn't booting
- Remove the disk and check to see if there is still a file system on it. Yet again, you can never be too sure.
- Check your charger with a multimeter. If the battery is dead and the charger ain't working, it won't boot up.